# Using NAudio to resample Wav audio data and convert to or from raw PCM

Tags: .net, wav, naudio

My server program takes audio data input from client software which is in PCM Wave format with correct RIFF header (48000 Hz, 16 bit, can be either 1 or 2 channels). Afterward, it needs to resample that data into 16000 Hz, 16 bit and only 1 channel with an exception: it has to be raw PCM data without any RIFF header so that the data can be transfer to an external service to be played. In addition, that service will stream back same type of raw PCM audio data. As such, the program will also need to the reverse (upsample to 48000Hz and in RIFF Wave format).

Currently, I am using NAudio to do much of the work since I need to do the process on the fly with binary data instead of saving it to a file and process that file.

Here is the code that I used for downsample and convert to raw:

```
var processingData = GetAudioData(); // This is the input audio data in Wav format
using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(processingData))
{
    using (var wavFileReader = new WaveFileReader(stream))
    {
        var resampler = new WdlResamplingSampleProvider(wavFileReader.ToSampleProvider(), 16000);
        var monoSource = resampler.ToMono().ToWaveProvider16();
        using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            byte[] bytesOutput = new byte[monoSource.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond];
            while (true)
            {
                int bytesRead = monoSource.Read(bytesOutput, 0, bytesOutput.Length);
                if (bytesRead == 0)
                    break;
                outputStream.Write(bytesOutput, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            var outputData = outputStream.ToArray(); // This is raw PCM data
        }
    }
}
```

I wonder if there is any better and efficient way to get the raw PCM from the WavProvider instead of reading it byte by byte into a `MemoryStream`. For example, I have tried the ACM resampler and it is a WaveStream, thus it is easy to copy the stream data to the memory stream, but that resampler could not change simultaneously sample rate as well as channel count. I want this part to be as fast as possible in order to get the raw PCM and send it quickly to the external service with minimal delay.

Similarly this is the reversing process logic code:

```
var processingData = GetRawData(); // This is the raw PCM data
using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(processingData))
{
    using (var rawStream = new RawSourceWaveStream(stream, new WaveFormat(16000, 16, 1)))
    using (var upsample = new WaveFormatConversionStream(new WaveFormat(48000, 16, 2), rawStream))
    using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        WaveFileWriter.WriteWavFileToStream(outputStream, upsample.ToSampleProvider().ToWaveProvider16());
        var outputData = outputStream.ToArray();
    }           
}
```

Since NAudio has some utilitie methods to generate Wave data, I used `WaveFileWriter.WriteWavFileToStream` method to generate all the necessary RIFF header, but instead of saving it to file, I transfer the data to a `MemoryStream`. Still I have some concerns about compatibility as well as efficient in this way. I believe `WaveFormatConversionStream` using ACM instead of Wdl so it could have some problem with the newer server software/hardware. Is there anyway to use the sample Wdl for this step as well like previously?